# What is ending a route

Tags: node.js, express

Supose i have this route code:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello world!');
});

app.get('/something', function(req, res) {
   // Do something
});
```

If i visit the / route in my browser, the "Hello world" message will show, and my response will have ended.

**Question:** Is it the absence of next() in this router, or the res.send() that ENDS the http request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `res.end()` that actually ends the response, but `res.send()` calls this.

You can see this in the source [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/master/lib/response.js#L164).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but if you want to log every request including '/' then you have to reorder using:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {

    // log each request to the console
    console.log(req.method, req.url);

    // continue doing what we were doing and go to the route
    next();
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.send('Hello world!');
});
```

Comment: Yes, i know this. 
Probably stupid of me to even add the logger middleware in this code example because is has nothing to do with my acctual question: **What ENDS the http request?**